# 8th generation Intel processor using 6/7 generation ports

Tags: drivers, cpu, pci-express, display-driver, intel-core-i5

My laptop has an **i5-8250u** CPU processor. However, few drivers are running on 6/7 generation versions. 
[Ports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILDw3.png)

I have no idea what these PCI ports do but is it something I should worry about? Do they affect the system performance?

Comment: What you have witnessed is perfectly normal and expected

Comment: @Ramhound oh ok. Thankyou!